# Stop a controlling object to move in Corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

I have 2 controls in a space shooter-like game, which are left and right.
The ship does move left and right and when the ship moves to the left of x=40 (far left), it will revert back to x=40 and disable the "move left" function temporarily, BUT my problem is that whenever I move to the far left or the far right of the screen, from the middle of the screen, the ship moves further than x=40(about x=35) then moves back and continues this until I let go of the button.
How can I make it so that when I move the ship to the far left, it stops completely and only lets me to move right?

Here is my code:

```
function left:touch()
if(car01.x>40 and car01.x<280) then
    motionx=-speed;
return false
end
end
left:addEventListener("touch",left)

function left:touch2()
    motionx=0;
end

local function movecar(event)
if(car01.x>40 and car01.x<280) then
    car01.x=car01.x+motionx
return false
elseif(car01.x==40) then
    car01.angularVelocity=0
    left:addEventListener("touch2",left)
    car01.x=car01.x+motionx
elseif(car01.x<40) then
    car01.x=40
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",movecar)

local function stop(event)
if (event.phase=="ended") then
    motionx=0;
    return true
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is is what you are looking for..?

Create a background(bg), left and right controls(left and right resp.). Then:

```
local function moveLeft()
  if(car01.x>40)then
    car01.x = car01.x - 40
  end
end
left:addEventListener("tap",moveLeft)

local function moveRight()
  if(car01.x<280)then
    car01.x = car01.x + 40
  end
end
right:addEventListener("tap",moveRight)
```

Keeo coding....... :)

Comment: Thx for the reply! but my problem is that my car01 object sort of moves outside the screen. By sort of, I mean even though I set up walls using display.newImage and physics.addBody, when I move car01 to the left by holding the left button I have created on the screen, car01 moves until the left half of the object is gone off the screen, then the whole object shifts just to the right of the left wall, then off the screen, then to the right of the left wall, and this continues on until I let go of the button.

Comment: is your car01 is also a physics body? Then it may due to the issue with it's collision with the wall. Try to increase the left border value(to 50 or 60). Then try again. Still the problem exists, then just use: car01.isSensor=true

Comment: Thank you for the reply again! I tried local left_wall=display.newRect(50,0,1,display.contentHeight) then physics.addBody(left_wall,"static") as well as car01.isSensor=true, but they didn't seem to fix the problem. I'm beginning to think this is the limit to Corona sdk. I sort of fixed the problem by setting the motionx=0 when the car01 reaches x=40, and the equation it follows is car01.x=car01.x+motionx. I'm not 100% satisfied, but it's better than before.